# How do I Improve efficiency of my solution for Project Euler #39?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

Ive used a brute force method and tried to improve efficiency as much as I can but I could only get to a perimeter of 680 after 1 hour. I need to get to 1000.

This is the question I was trying to solve:

> If p is the perimeter of a right angle triangle with integral length       > sides, {a,b,c}, there are exactly three solutions for p = 120.
>
> {20,48,52}, {24,45,51}, {30,40,50}
>
> For which value of p ≤ 1000, is the number of solutions maximised?

https://projecteuler.net/problem=39

In my solution I've added comments for every line to explain what it does.

Ive used Python 3.

```
import math

# Initialisation of variables:
max = 0
ans = 0

# 'i' represents the perimeter. 'c' represents the hypotenuse length. 'a' and 'b' are both sides lengths:

# This outer loop iterates through all the perimeters from 1 to 1000.
for i in range(1, 1001):
    # Resets the count and arrA values.
    count = 0
    arrA = []
    # This loop iterates through all the hypotenuse values and makes sure its less than half of the perimeter:
    for c in range(1, i // 2):
        # This loop iterates through all the b values where b is lesser than (perimeter - hypotenuse):
        for b in range(1, i - c):
            # This loop iterates through all the a values where 'a' is lesser than (perimeter - hypotenuse - other side + 1):
            for a in range(1, i - c - b + 1):
                # Makes sure that all sides add up to the perimeter and that hypotenuse is lesser than the sum of the 2 other sides.
                if a + b + c != i or a + b <= c:
                    continue
                # Makes sure no instances are being repeated by and b being switched:
                if b in arrA:
                    break
                # Checks if its a right angled triangle:
                if math.sqrt(math.pow(a, 2) + math.pow(b, 2)) == c:
                    #Adds to the number of matches for the current perimeter.
                    count += 1
                    # Adds a to arrA so b can check later:
                    arrA.append(a)
                    # Extra output line for testing purposes (not needed):
                    print([f'{a:4}', f'{b:4}', f'{c:4}', f'{i:4}', f'{count:4}'])
    # checks if the current count was a new maximum or equal to previous maximum:
    if count >= max:
        max = count
        ans = i

#Prints final output:
print(f'Final Answer: {ans}')
```

The following is the exact same code as the above but without comments for easier readability:

```
import math

max = 0
ans = 0

for i in range(1, 1001):
    count = 0
    arrA = []
    for c in range(1, i // 2):
        for b in range(1, i - c):
            for a in range(1, i - c - b + 1):
                if a + b + c != i or a + b <= c:
                    continue
                if b in arrA:
                    break
                if math.sqrt(math.pow(a, 2) + math.pow(b, 2)) == c:
                    count += 1
                    arrA.append(a)
                    print([f'{a:4}', f'{b:4}', f'{c:4}', f'{i:4}', f'{count:4}'])

    if count >= max:
        max = count
        ans = i

print(f'Final Answer: {ans}')
```

It didn't finish even in 2 hours but it got the perimeter to 800 so I know it was working, just extremely slowly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Think about how many times you calculate `math.sqrt(math.pow(a, 2) + math.pow(b, 2))` for the same values of `a` and `b`. It would be better for any given `a` and `b` to only do that math once.

Comment: Hint:  You have *four* for-loops nested.  You can still easily brute-force it with only *two* for-loops.

Comment: you might wana get your maths checked out https://math.stackexchange.com/ first then concentrate on code.

Comment: A few hints: for a given `p`, if `a` is the longest side of the square angle, it can't be as small as you want (look for a minimal value), neither greater than `p/2`. For each `p` and `a`, you can calculate `b` and `c` directly, you just have to check that they are integers. Based on this, it takes me less than 50 ms - so even without the bounds for `a`, it would take much less than a second.

Comment: @wim how though? I'm not able to think of a way to do that.